# How to export from SQL Server to XML

Tags: sql-server, ssis, xmltask

What is the easiest way to export to XML from SQL Server [Table or view] to XML?

This is what I have done till now

**Execute Sql Task**

```
SELECT * FROM Production.Product 
FOR XML AUTO, TYPE, ROOT('Data')
```

*ResultSet* XML

in left result set section I have created new variable 0 User::XMLVal

**Script Task**

```
 Dim sw As New IO.StreamWriter("D:\Apps\SSIS\test.xml")
    sw.Write(Dts.Variables("User::XMLVal").Value.ToString())


    sw.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use the task components, set up an `Execute SQL Task` to read the result of a SQL statement or stored procedure into a user-defined SSIS variable. Your statement above is a good example of what it should look like:

[image]

Then use the `XML Task` to write the contents of the variable to a file:

[image]

Comment: But i am not gettin XML datatype. I am using 2005. I tried with Nvarchar but it fails **[Execute SQL Task] Error: There is an invalid number of result bindings returned for the ResultSetType: "ResultSetType_XML".**

Comment: @Zerotoinfinite Make sure your `Execute SQL Task` has its `ConnectionType` property set to `ADO.NET`, `ResultSet = None`, and use `OUTPUT` parameters to get the values from a stored procedure call.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the query in a data flow source adapter and use the Export Column Transformation --- [Using SSIS to extract a XML representation of table data to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9104123/using-ssis-to-extract-a-xml-representation-of-table-data-to-a-file)

This saves you the trouble of managing your own scripts and what not, it's all out of the box functionality.