# Export Varbinary(max) column with ssis

Tags: ssis

we've a table with a varbinary(max) column, the column is used for a Rich text field in the Application  (**not for Attaching docs**) . 
I'm trying to export the column into a flat file through a very simple ssis package. 
my package contain oledb cource and flat file destination .

when i opened the flat file output , i've found out to my surprise the the data was truncated to 255 characters, do you have any idea how to export all the data completely?

Thx for the help .

Comment: Is the intention that this field is only thing in the output file or would it look something like col1|col2|col3varbinmax?

Comment: It wont be the only field in the output file , the table contains also ordinary datatypes such as int and varchar .

Comment: Could you provide an example of your expected output then? Truncate the varbinary data obviously

Answer (score 3):

Whilst awaiting clarification on how you intend to use it, I'd suggest looking at the [Export Column Transformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms139818.aspx). Similar need on this question 
[Using SSIS to extract a XML representation of table data to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9104123/using-ssis-to-extract-a-xml-representation-of-table-data-to-a-file/9105756#9105756)

I banged out a quick example that illustrates how to do export varbinary data. The following query concatenates some strings together before casting them as varbinary(max). It also generates a second column which will be the output file used.

```
WITH STARTER(starter) AS
(
    -- some simple data
    SELECT 'a'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'b'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'c'
)
,  VCM(longenough) AS
(
    SELECT
        CAST(REPLICATE(T.starter, 8000) AS varchar(max))
    FROM
        STARTER T
)
SELECT
    CAST(V0.longenough + V1.longenough AS varbinary(max)) AS BlobData
,   'C:\ssisdata\filename.' + CAST(row_number() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS varchar(10)) + '.txt' AS FileName
FROM
    VCM V0
    CROSS APPLY
    VCM V1;
```

Configuring SSIS is a snap. I used the above query as my source.
[image: Simple data flow]

I ensured the metadata looked as expected - yup, the BLobData column is an image

[image: metadata]

Configure the Export Column transformation. If the file already exists, the task will fail as shown. You would either need to check the Allow Append or Force Truncate option.

[image: Export Column Transformation editor]

Comment: Could you provide an example of what your expected output would be? How should it behave when an embedded carriage returns in the varbinary data?

Comment: Hi, We'll probably have to be settle with the export column comp. and add another column with the file path . thx for your help