# Junk characters at the beginning of file obtained via column transformations in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I need to export varbinary data to file. But, when I do it using Column Transformations in SSIS, the exported files are corrupt. There are few junk characters at the start of the file. On removing them, the file opens fine.

A [similar post for BCP](http://bytes.com/topic/sql-server/answers/844661-bcp-out-image-files-not-working), says that these characters specify the data length.

Would like to know how to address this issue in SSIS?

Thanks

Comment: I have not had issues with the Export Column Transformation task. Could you elaborate on what your package looks like, the source structure, etc? Gowdhaman008's answer looks comparable to mine [Export varbinary max](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12712632/export-varbinarymax-column-with-ssis/12713897#12713897)

Answer (score 0):

Export transformation is used for converting the varbinary to files.I have tried something similar using Adventure works which has image type of var-binary data.

1. Following Query is used for the Source query. I have Modified the query
   since it does not have the full path to write image files.

   ```
   SELECT [ProductPhotoID]
         ,[ThumbNailPhoto]
         ,'D:\SSISTesting\ThumnailPhotos\'+[ThumbnailPhotoFileName]
         ,[LargePhoto]
         ,'D:\SSISTesting\LargePhotos\'+[LargePhotoFileName]
         ,[ModifiedDate]
   FROM [Production].[ProductPhoto]
   ```
2. Used the Export column transformation[also available in [2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms139818%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) and
   [2008]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms139818%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and configured as follows.
   [image]
3. Mapped rest of the columns to the destination.
4. After running package all the image files are written into the
   respective folders[D:\SSISTesting\ThumnailPhotos\ and D:\SSISTesting\LargePhotos].

Hope this helps!