# Using DocuSign API with SSIS to retrieve documents

Tags: ssis, docusignapi

I am using the HTTP connection manager in SSIS with the JSON source connector to initiate the API calls to DocuSign.  I am able to return the JSON source and map the columnar data into an OLEDB destination connector.

[image]

I am unable to figure out how to manage the binary payload of the actual file and download it to a specific file folder on my network.  Do you have suggestions for how I can do this via SSIS?

My end goal is to retrieve the signed DocuSign documents and their metadata so that I can upload the documents to an OnBase document management platform AND user the metadata to drive our CRM based business processes.

I am using this rest API call: `/restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents/{documentId}` 
in my JSON source container and I haven't figured out how to pipe the file payload to the file system. The call should be returning a PDF file that I can save to a folder named after the envelopeID with a document name. I am able to get the DocusSign retrieve tool to do this, but I am trying to get the entire process into an SSIS job.

Comment: Are you using a DocuSign connect webhook call? can you explain how you set this up? I'm not clear as you talking about download, so it is initiated by an API call? which one?

Comment: We have some code examples on how to download documents, in a "pull" approach, but not sure if that's what you want to do.

Comment: [Export Column Transformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12712632/export-varbinarymax-column-with-ssis/12713897#12713897) is how you would take a column and make a file out of each row

Comment: I highly recommend a console app using c# and the nuget package (1.3M downloads) they offer.